# Accessing Javascript Array to placemarkers on Google Map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have an array:

```
var = CITIES {
  "Buenos Aires":
  {latitude: -34.6084, longitude: -58.3732},
  "Santiago":
  {latitude: -33.4254, longitude: -70.5665},
  "Gaborone":
  {latitude: -24.6541, longitude: 25.9087},
...
};
```

I need to place markers on a 2D Google Map; I try to do it with this function:

```
/*
 * void
 * mark()
 *
 * Markes locations of study abroad programs all around the world map
 */

function mark()
{
    // mark programs
    for (var city in CITIES)
    {
        // plant cities on map
        new google.maps.Marker({
         icon: "http://google-maps-icons.googlecode.com/files/smallcity.png",
         map: map,
         position: new google.maps.LatLng(CITIES[city].latitude, CITIES[city].longitude),
         title: 'CITIES[city]'
        });
    }
}
```

The js console is giving me an error saying that:

```
missing variable name
[Break on this error] var = CITIES {\n
```

I know the error has to do with me accessing CITIES with city parameter, but how do I fix this and access the necessary information?

Comment: So the error seems to have gone. But what do I need to do to make the placemarks appear?

Answer (score 0):

`var = CITIES {` is wrong, use `var CITIES = {` instead.

First say that you want to create a variable (`var`), then specify its name (`CITIES`) and then assign a value (optionally, `=...`).

Comment: So the error seems to have vanished. But, the placemarks still don't appear on the map. Any idea how I can make them appear?

Comment: Also, thank you for all your help! This has been a lifesaver!