# Accessing JS Array to Place Markers on 2D Google Map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Accessing Javascript Array to placemarkers on Google Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4398631/accessing-javascript-array-to-placemarkers-on-google-map)

I have an array:

```
var CITIES = {
  "Buenos Aires":
  {latitude: -34.6084, longitude: -58.3732},
  "Santiago":
  {latitude: -33.4254, longitude: -70.5665},
  "Gaborone":
  {latitude: -24.6541, longitude: 25.9087},
...
}
```

I need to place markers on a 2D Google Map; I try to do that with this function:

```
/*
 * void
 * mark()
 *
 * Markes locations of study abroad programs all around the world map
 */

function mark()
{
    // mark programs
    for (var city in CITIES)
    {
        // plant cities on map
        new google.maps.Marker({
         icon: "http://google-maps-icons.googlecode.com/files/smallcity.png",
         map: map,
         position: new google.maps.LatLng(CITIES[city].latitude, CITIES[city].longitude),
         title: 'CITIES[city]'
        });
    }
}
```

There's no error on the console.

How do I make the markers appear? (Does the error have to do with me referring to CITIES[city])?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To the right of your question, when you were typing it, was a box labelled **How to Format**. Worth a read. :-)

Comment: Actually this **isn't** a duplicate of the OP's previous question. The previous question was about a syntax error that is not present in the above.

Comment: Don't post the same question twice. Instead update your previous question with the new information. @T.J. Crowder: Yes, but the actual problem is the same.... imo these two questions are too close to each other.

Comment: I apologize for all this urgency, n00bness and sounding like a distressed child, but this really is an emergency. I need to make these markers appear some how and then get this code out.

Answer (score 1):

### Zoom

Are you zoomed in too far? Because it works for me if you deal with the issues below ([live example](http://jsbin.com/osune3/2)):

```
// Note that this script is just before the closing body
// tag, so we can access items above by their ID and such.
// To avoid clashes, avoid creating any public symbols
// by using an anonymous scoping function.
(function() {
  // Our map
  var map;

  // Our cities
  var CITIES = {
    "Buenos Aires":
    {latitude: -34.6084, longitude: -58.3732},
    "Santiago":
    {latitude: -33.4254, longitude: -70.5665},
    "Gaborone":
    {latitude: -24.6541, longitude: 25.9087}
  };

  // Call our load function
  map = load();

  // Set up our handler on the button
  // (I don't recommend using `onclick` generally, I
  // recommend using a library that deals with the
  // addEventListener/attachEvent issue for you; just
  // using it here for simplicity.)
  document.getElementById('btnAdd').onclick = addMarkers;

  // Our load function
  function load() {
    var latlng, myOptions;

    // Get the map
    latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.6084, -58.3732);
    myOptions = {
      zoom: 3,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    return new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        myOptions);
  }

  // Add markers
  function addMarkers() {

    var cityName, city;

    for (cityName in CITIES)
    {
        city = CITIES[cityName];

        // plant cities on map
        new google.maps.Marker({
         icon: "http://google-maps-icons.googlecode.com/files/smallcity.png",
         map: map,
         position: new google.maps.LatLng(city.latitude, city.longitude),
         title: cityName
        });
    }
  }

  // The end of our anonymous scoping function; we call
  // it immediately.
})();
```

### Issues with `map`

<s>In your `mark` function, you're using the variable `map`. It's not defined in any of the code you've quoted, is it defined in the enclosing scope? If not, that might well be the problem.</s>

You've commented below that it's a global variable, saying it's `var map = null;`. I don't think it can be `null`, though, it should be a `Map` or `StreetViewPanorama` instance according to [the docs](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#MarkerOptions). E.g., like this example from ["the basics" tutorial](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial.html):

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
                              myOptions);
```

### Issues with `CITIES[city]`

If you want to access the value `CITIES[city]`, instead of

```
title: 'CITIES[city]'
```

you want

```
title: CITIES[city]
```

(No quotes) But I think it's more likely you just want:

```
title: city
```

...because `CITIES[city]` is an object, and you probably want the city name, not the default stringification of the object (which will be `[object Object]`).

(No quotes). So:

```
for (var city in CITIES)
{
    // plant cities on map
    new google.maps.Marker({
     icon: "http://google-maps-icons.googlecode.com/files/smallcity.png",
     map: map,
     position: new google.maps.LatLng(CITIES[city].latitude, CITIES[city].longitude),
     title: city
    });
}
```

---

### Off-topic #1

I'd probably cache the lookup, although a decent JavaScript implementation will do it for you (there are lots of bad ones that probably won't):

```
var cityName, city;

for (cityName in CITIES)
{
    city = CITIES[cityName];

    // plant cities on map
    new google.maps.Marker({
     icon: "http://google-maps-icons.googlecode.com/files/smallcity.png",
     map: map,
     position: new google.maps.LatLng(city.latitude, city.longitude),
     title: cityName
    });
}
```

---

### Off-topic #2

`CITIES` is not an array. It's a non-array object. But that's fine, the `for..in` loop you're using is for looping through [object properties (not array indexes)](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/11/myths-and-realities-of-forin.html) anyway, so that works out. :-)

---

### Off-topic #3

You need a `;` at the end of your `CITIES` declaration:

```
var CITIES = {
    ....
}; // <== here
```

JavaScript's semicolon insertion will provide it for you assuming there's a line break following the `}`, but it's never a good idea to rely on semicolon insertion.

Comment: Thank you!

That does help things out, but it still doesn't make the markers appear on the map!

Comment: I apologize for sounding so dramatic and distressed, but this is really an emergency. I need to get this code out - the markers just won't appear!

Comment: @John Q: Good luck with it. I've updated the answer a bit (mostly at the top), might help.

Comment: // global reference to map
var map = null;

Comment: Should map be defined differently?

Comment: @John Q: According to the docs, it has to be defined. `null` probably isn't a valid option, it should be a `Map` or `StreetViewPanorama` instance: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#MarkerOptions

Comment: @John Q: `map` should hold a reference to your Google Map. [The documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Marker) is clear: *Creates a marker with the options specified. **If a map is specified, the marker is added to the map upon construction**.* So unless `map` is defined , you have to add the marker manually to the map.

Comment: @Felix Kling I don't think I understood that. I define map in another function called load. Should I define it globally as well?

Comment: function load()
{
    // embed map
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(LATITUDE, LONGITUDE);
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
     center: latlng,
     disableDefaultUI: true,
     mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
     navigationControl: true,
     scrollwheel: true,
     zoom: 1
   });
}

Comment: @John Q: `map` needs to be declared at the scope containing the `mark` function. It needs to refer to a `Map` or `StreetViewPanorama` instance at the time `mark` is called. If it's a `var` *inside* your `load` function, that won't work unless `mark` is also defined *inside* your `load` function. If `map` is declared in the enclosing scope and *initialized* by your `load` function, that's fine provided it happens before `mark` is called.

Comment: @John Q: If `map` is global and you call `load()` before `mark()` then it should actually work. Check the value of `map` inside your `mark` function with `console.log(map)`.

Comment: map seems to be fine

Still doesn't place the markers.

Comment: I even re-embed the map by rewriting the map definition with the scope of mark() - doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: @John: I've added a working example using your `CITIES` object at the top of my answer. Works for me.

Comment: Thank you guys for all your help.

One final request: would it be possible for you to look at the code below?

Answer (score 0):

// default latitude
var LATITUDE = 42.3745615030193;

// default longitude
var LONGITUDE = -71.11803936751632;

// global reference to map
var map;

// load version 3 of the Google Maps API
google.load("maps", "3", {other_params: "sensor=false"});

/*
 * void
 * load()
 *
 * Loads map.
 */

function load() 
{
    var latlng, myOptions;

```
// Get the map
latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(LATITUDE, LONGITUDE);
myOptions = {
  zoom: 3,
  center: latlng,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
return new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
    myOptions);
```

}

/*
 * void
 * mark()
 *
 * Markes locations of study abroad programs all around the world map
 */

function mark()
{
    var cityName, city;

```
for (cityName in CITIES)
{
city = CITIES[cityName];

// plant cities on map
new google.maps.Marker({
 icon: "http://google-maps-icons.googlecode.com/files/smallcity.png",
 map: map,
 position: new google.maps.LatLng(city.latitude, city.longitude),
 title: cityName
});
}
```

}

Harvard Abroad: Mapped

```
  <div id="top">
    <a href="index.php"><img alt="Harvard Abroad" src="Images/logo.jpg"></a>
  </div>

  <div id="logo">
    Harvard Abroad: Mapped
  </div>

  <div id="button">
    <input onclick="mark();" type="button" value="Map">
  </div>

  <div id="map">
  </div>

  <div id="bottom">
  |
  <a href="index.php" style="font-weight: bold">index</a>
  |
  <a href="search.php" style="font-weight: bold">search</a>
  |
  <a href="comment.php" style="font-weight: bold">comment</a>
  |
  <a href="viewcomment.php" style="font-weight: bold">view comments</a>      
  |
  <a href="logout.php" style="font-weight: bold">log out</a>
  |
  </div>
```

Comment: There's what I have now. Displays the map, not the markers.

Comment: I need some help! Ahhhh!

Comment: John, please don't use answers to clarify your question. Instead, edit the question. (And again, as with the question, proper formatting would help.)

Comment: Hey T.J., my apologies

Just going back to your live example - I don't see the placemarkers on the map. The map seems to load fine, even for me. It's just that the markers don't appear on the map.

Comment: Did you click the button? I add the markers at that point. For me, it works perfectly: On load, the map appears. When I click the button, the markers appear.